# Fastest way to enable / disable a large number of select options

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've got a select element with just over 2000 options. I'm updating which options can be selected based on the value of another select within the same form. The code I'm using currently is:

```
var $options = $('#myOptions option');
$('#view').on('change', function() {    
  let view = $(this).val();
  if (view == 'all') {
    $options.removeProp('disabled');
  } else {
    $options.removeProp('disabled').not('option[data-view="' + view + '"]' ).prop('disabled', true);
  }
});
```

This code works perfectly and the options update almost instantly in Chrome or Firefox, but it takes IE and Edge 10+ seconds.

So my question is - is this the fastest way to enable or disable a large number of options? If not, what is the best way? Thanks in advance.

p.s - Probably worth noting that I'm using the following library https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/

Comment: The ids are unique, those selectors target the `<select>` elements

Comment: It's most likely a rendering slowdown with IE, one idea.  Detach the view from the DOM, update, and then re-attach.  You could also maybe just try making the View invisible & visible too.

Comment: How is a user supposed to navigate 2000 options in the first place?

Comment: The fastest way to update a bunch of HTML nodes is always to only do one update instead of updating every node seperately. So if speed is an concern, I would just take the parent node of the options, update all the children that need updating and then reinsert the parent node, so that all updates get rendered in one go instead of each update triggering a DOM change.

Comment: @charlietfl Thats where typings come into play. I had a requirement where I had 9k+ options. gnusey, 1 word of advice, it will cause lot of lag on mobile browser. Its better to create a typeahead. I had to limit options to few hundred at a time and added a note for user to search instead.

Comment: @gnusey Also, instead of *enable/disable*, replace HTML and *hide/show* options. When you have such a component, more than JS performance, HTML performance come into play. You will see lag in devices(*not iPhone though*) that have less RAM.

Comment: @Rajesh makes a good point. I would definitely not run this box on mobile. The only thing I can think of is that you're listing inventory/SKUs ? I don't know what else would have 5k or 9k of something. A lot of internal inventory places that I've worked( and I've never built one so this is from an end user perspective) will narrow down the choices significantly by other variables before populating a select box.

Comment: im assuming that of the 2000 options only a handful are visible at once, in which case is may be quicker to empty the select and then repopulate with only the valid options after passing the filter to the source that provides your options, anything java base is likely to be slow in IE because they haven't updated the java engine in quite a while

Comment: @Rajesh The bootstrap-select library I'm using provides a typeahead feature fortunately (which I've got enabled). I was just looking to further filter the options list to make the it easier for the end user because, as charlie says, 2000 is a lot of options. I'll look into some of your other suggestions :)

Comment: @gnusey irrespective of library, nothing can meet performance of vanilla element. So `select` will perform better always. 1 option you can try is to limit 100 items and then if user scrolls to 100th option, add another 100 more. But that will make DOM heavy and slow. If you really want to create a performant component, use JS as JS processing is faster then DOM. Instead of changing attribute, add/remove element. Replacing html will be the fastest option. And do check on old non-iPhone mobile to understand the performance. Best of luck

Comment: @Rajesh Thanks Rajesh. I'll let you know if I crack it!

Comment: @Rajesh hide/show options is not supported cross browser. Agree a typeahead/autocomplete would make more sense also just from a UX standpoint

Comment: @charlietfl by hide/show, i meant rewrite html with only required elements. Changing attr of such a long list will be a nightmare. Best option is to maintain a hashmap of data and on search clear everything and show only required options.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone interested, the way I got around this issue was relatively simple. Rather than have each option with their own `data-view` attribute I moved them into `<optgroup>` elements and targeted the data attribute on that.

This reduced the number of html attributes being adjusted by the code from thousands to just over ten.

```
var $optGrps = $('#myOptions optgroup');
$('#view').on('change', function() {    
    let view = $(this).val();
    if (view == 'all') {
        $optGrps.prop( 'disabled', false );
    } else {
        $optGrps.prop( 'disabled', false ).not('optgroup[data-view="' + view + '"]' ).prop('disabled', true);
   }
});
```

I know this doesn't *strictly* answer the question **Fastest way to enable / disable a large number of select options**, but it was the easiest and least time consuming solution I could find.